# Redirection of url angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm building an app and i have a little problem.

For the index, i change my url with history.pushstate when i click on a button with jquery.
For example, `www.mysite.com` become `www.mysite.com/something` without reloading the page. But if a load this page i don't find `www.mysite.com` because "something" doesn't exist.

And I don't know how do the link between them.

I tried to do this but it doesn't work with AngularJS.

```
var myApp = angular.module('photo', ['ngRoute']);


myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'machin.html'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/something-one', {
        templateUrl: 'machin.html'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/something-two', {
        templateUrl: 'machin.html'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

This is the way to do it or I'm just lost ? ^^

---

#### Solved

My solution works sorry all. I forgot the script angular-route but the rest of my script works.

Comment: You can use $route.current = "/url"

Answer (score 1):

In your button, you can bind event using `ng-click` instead of using jQuery.

```
<button ng-click="goto('/something')">Go to something</button>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.goto = function(url) {
   $location.path(url);
}
```

When you're working with Jquery, you're out of angular scope. So angular will not know about the URL change. You may need to trigger `digest` cycle in that case.

Comment: Yes thanks but i need "something" to be referencied and with location.path it's after the hash. I don't want the reload of the page so i asking myself if it's possible.

Comment: No it's not possible. Because it's not there in your routes and so angular will redirect to default route `/`

Comment: My solution works :D sorry for your lost of time and thanks a lot. I forgot to include angular-route to my html.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
var myApp = angular.module('photo', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'machin.html'
    })
    .when('/something-one', {
        templateUrl: 'machin.html'
    })
    .when('/something-two', {
        templateUrl: 'machin.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

and in your html

```
<a href="#/something-one">Go to something one</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i my solution worked too i did a little mistake ^^ Thanks for your time.